# Not able to generate a chart-php

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I am creating bar chart , i am unable to get output and generate chart.

here is my code

```
if ($sql) {
    $arrData = array(
        "chart" => array(
            "caption" => "Status stastics",
            "showValues" => "0",
            "theme" => "zune"
        )
   );
   $arrData["data"] = array();

   foreach($sql as $row)  {
       array_push($arrData["data"], array(
           "label" => $row["name"],
           "value" => $row["value"]
       )
       var_dump($row["value"]);
       );
    }
}
```

I am not getting any output for ( var_dump($row["value"]);)
am i going in a right way?
Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Isn't this `var_dump` a syntax error ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix you were telling about syntax error??

Comment: yes, you put the var_dump in the `array_push` function. But there is no comma after the array with label and value to start with. I think this is a syntax error. Do you have error reporting on ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix yes error reporting is on but i don't find any errors.

Comment: but it shows fatal error--> Cannot use object of type stdClass

Comment: and i converted object type to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got  my answer

```
if ($sql) {
$arrData = array(
"chart" => array(
"caption" => "Status stastics",
"showValues" => "0",
"theme" => "zune"
  )
  );
$arrData["data"] = array();

foreach($sql as $row)
{
$object_array =(array)$row;
array_push($arrData["data"], array(
"label" => $object_array["name"],
"value" => $object_array["value"]
 )
 );
}

}
?>
```